# How to increment badge count with firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, swift, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Right now my payload only sends 1 badge count, the value of the badge count does not increment. It remains as 1, even if you get more than 1 notifications.

How should the javascript be written?

My current code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');                   
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); 
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendPushForHelp = 
functions.database.ref('/help/school/{id}').onWrite(event => {
   const payLoad = {
     notification: {
         title: 'Someone',
         body: 'needs help',
         badge: '1',
         sound: 'Intruder.mp3'
     }
   };
   return admin.database().ref('fcmToken').once('value').then(allToken => {
       if (allToken.val()) {
        const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payLoad).then(response => {

            });
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: can't you just make a incremental int and set the `badge` value in the const payLoad equal to that?

Comment: You mean that I should include the incremental int in xcode (swiftcode). And then I should use that variable in the payload. Lets say badge: badgecount?

Comment: That could work, I was even suggesting storing the var in the JS

Comment: Could you please give me an example? I am very new to JS. Where should you declare the variable?

Comment: sure i'll do a quick write up in the answer

Comment: Thank you, however it did not work. "badgeCount = ++;
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", got this error.

Comment: just use like this `badgeCount++` it'll auto-assign the value. feel free to use this as the selected answer if it helped your problem :)

Comment: Sorry for the many replies but it does not work. Because when you export the function to firebase cloud functions you get an error. The error is: "badgeCount++
            ^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: Minor issue with the scope sorry, work just got a little bit busy, I'll swing around in a bit but see if you can pass the badgeCount var into your firebase function

Comment: sorry for the radio silence, just got back home, did you get this squared away

Answer (score 4):

You can store a `badgeCount` in your JS and have it increment on every call, or randomize it or what have you

ie:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');                   
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); 
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var badgeCount = 1;
exports.sendPushForHelp = 
functions.database.ref('/help/school/{id}').onWrite(event => {
   const payLoad = {
     notification: {
         title: 'Someone',
         body: 'needs help',
         badge: badgeCount.toString(),
         sound: 'Intruder.mp3'
     }
   };
   badgeCount++; //or whatever
   return admin.database().ref('fcmToken').once('value').then(allToken => {
       if (allToken.val()) {
        const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payLoad).then(response => {
          //here might be a good place to increment as well, only on success
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't account for if badge counts get cleared on open or some action within the app, no?